# How to force mstest in C# to give the outcome of timeout to a test?

Tags: c#, mstest

We have a service that we are testing the will sometimes take a long time to return a result. When this happens we want the outcome to be a timeout.

To determine whether out tests succeed or fail we use the assert class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=visualstudiosdk-2022. We tried using the assert.inconclusive("blah blah") but mstest records that as a NotExecuted.

What I do no want to do is change the overall timeout of all my tests, I just want to force the result timeout on a few when a certain event occurs.

We tried using the assert class but it appears you can not force a timeout

Comment: Side note: I see no reason why you object longer timeouts for integration tests. For unit testing you'd obviously mock the service and throw timeout exception instantly instead of having the rest of the code to wait...

Comment: If the test doesn’t run to completion because of the timeout then surely that **is** an inconclusive result?